# Custom Layer not supporting serialized custom activation function

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

since the release of version 2.6 of Tensorflow I am having a issue I did not have with version 2.5.

The following code works OK:

```
from tensorflow.keras.utils import get_custom_objects
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense

def my_act(x):
  return x

get_custom_objects().update({"my_act": my_act})

dense = Dense(3, activation="my_act")
```

However, if I try to do the same but with a custom layer instead of Tensorflow built-in layers, I have the error:

```
ValueError: Unknown activation function: my_act. Please ensure this object is passed to the `custom_objects` argument. See https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize#registering_the_custom_object for details.
```

[Here](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/NEGU93/f2fa1b14445c72cf6f86f5d175e3997a/bug_with_new_release.ipynb) you have the minimum code to reproduce plus I show that with version 2.5 works ok (You need to restart the runtime to run it tho).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to import `activations` like this:

```
from tensorflow.keras import activations
```

instead of `from tensorflow.python.keras import activations`.

In tensorflow 2.7 and later versions `tensorflow.python` will no longer exist, and it seems in TF 2.6 already it is not compatible with some other functions.